# CakePHP login from different views

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, view

I'm using CakePHP 3.6 and I want to allow the user to login from different views. I have 2 forms that are the same, but one is on every page and the another one is only in 1 page.
Let me show you that:

[image: You can see this mini form is on every page]

[image: You can see this mini form is on every page]

[image: You can see that this page has the two forms that are the same.]

Here's my initialize function of AppControler

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
        'enableBeforeRedirect' => false,
    ]);
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authorize'=> 'Controller',
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
         // If unauthorized, return them to page they were just on
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer()
    ]);

}
```

Here's my login function of UsersController:

```
public function login()
{

    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            $this->Flash->success('You logged succesfully!');
            return $this->redirect($this->referer());
        }

        // Invalid login
        $this->Flash->error('Incorrect login');
    }
}
```

Here's the form (remember they are the same):

```
<?php if(!$loggedIn): ?>
    <?= $this->Form->create(null, ['class' => 'form-signin']) ?>

        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2>
        <?= $this->Form->input('email', ['required' => true, 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Email', 'label' => false]) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('password', ['type' => 'password', 'required' => true, 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Contraseña', 'label' => false]) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('remember', ['type' => 'checkbox', 'value' => 'remember-me']) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->submit('Entrar', ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block' ]); ?>

    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The problem seems pretty obvious to me but I don't know how to solve it. The form that's in all the views it's not working, but only in the Users view. It seems like the login action it's only working if I'm in the Users view...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply change to url in the form that's in every view so that the POST data is sent to users/login

```
echo $this->Form->create(null, [
    'class' => 'form-signin', 
    'url' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']
]);
```

Comment: Thanks man! That was exactly what I needed to do, but now I have problem with token: '_Token' was not found in request data. How do i fix it?

Comment: do you have security component enabled?

Comment: Yes, I want it to te enabled, but i don't know why i'm having that error.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think is because the security component does not let you send data from a controller to another. Or maybe you loaded this component just for usersController and you don't have form tampering control in the other views

Comment: I have loaded the security component in the initialize function of AppController.

Comment: Solved! I just had to load the security component in the beforeFilter function. My bad... Thanks you!